# Joint Probability with many values

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider I have the following tree structure which provides the relation between various entities.

[image]

Associated with this, I have the following table with data.

```
income  exercise    smoke   bmi bp  cholesterol angina  attack  stroke  diabetes
yes     no          yes     no  yes no          no      no      no      no
yes     yes         no      yes no  no          no      no      no      no
no      yes         no      no  no  no          no      no      no      no
...
```

Now how to calculate the joint probability distribution for something like below

1) P( (stroke = yes) | ( Income = yes, exercise = no, smoke = no) )

2) P( ( angina = no, diabetes = yes) | ( income = no, bmi = no, smoke = yes ) )

**Note**

I have tried along the lines as Henry has answered. But that solution would have worked if the entities are not dependent on each other. Since entities do depend on each other, I cannot apply the same method

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit how you tried to solve it, so other people could help you better. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are treating your data as the population, rather than a sample, then for Q1 you count the number of cases which meet the criteria *"stroke = yes, income = yes, exercise = no, and smoke = no"* and divide by the number which meet the criteria *"income = yes, exercise = no, and smoke = no"*.

Similarly for Q2 you count the number of cases which meet the criteria *"angina = no, diabetes = yes, income = no, bmi = no, and smoke = yes"* and divide by the number which meet the criteria *"income = no, bmi = no, and smoke = yes"*.

***Added:***  What you are supposed to do is look at each of the circles on the graph.  Suppose it has $n$ incoming arrows: that means there are $2^n$ possible combinations of inputs and for each of these you are supposed to calculate the conditional probabilities of that status.  For example for *bmi*, you have to calculate the $4$ conditional probabilities given the *income* status and *exercise* status.  Having done that for the whole graph, you then take the input information (in the first question *income = yes, exercise = no, and smoke = no*), calculate the intermediate conditional probabilities (*bmi, bp, cholesterol*) and then the final consitional probability (*stroke*).

Comment: Exactly, even I tried that, but that is not the correct answer. That is applicable only if the entities are independent of each other, but these are dependent on one another as given in the graph. So this calls for joint distribution and conditional probability

Comment: @Novice123: my answer does not depend on the features being independent of each other

Comment: It does. U cannot ignore other variables involved in joint distribution

Comment: @Novice123: In fact the position is the opposite. My answer may not fit the graph in the question, as the graph suggests, for example, that given *bmi* status, *diabetes* status is independent of *income* status, while my answer does not.